# Web to case form - how to send hidden checkbox value to backend in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am using web to case for if I use below

```
<input id="xxxx" name="xxx" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>
```

then value is getting saved i.e true

If I used

```
<input hidden="true" id="xxxx" name="xxx" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>
```

value not saving into the DB. I dont want to show checkbox on the screen, but always wants to send true value to backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code its hard to guess the problem, Only thing would be with hidden attribute in the form.

It its not mandatory to use `hidden` attribute, try hiding it with CSS:

```
<input id="xxxx" name="xxx" type="checkbox" value="1" style="display: none;"/>
```

Note: Best practice would be to use classes instead of inline style if possible.